# Transfer list from .ts to .tsx

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, spfx, office-ui-fabric

I have a list that i get from SharePoint, and i want to use it as an items in my DropDownList in the .tsx file, i did it, but i have problem, i don't see items when i executed. But when i click on the dropDown, the items appear.
When i debug the list which i get are realy empty in the first, it only fills up when i click on the DropDownList, i don't understand why my list are empty, i have same probleme whith all lists in my code.

.ts

```
export default class DropWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IDropPartProps> {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IFaqProps> = React.createElement(drop, {
      dropList: this.getDropList()
    });
    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }
  public getDropList(): IDropdownOption[] {
    let dropList: IDropdownOption[] = new Array();
    this._getData().then(response => {
      response.forEach((itemc: IOptionCategorie) => {
        dropList.push({ key: itemc.Categorie, text: itemc.Key });
      });
    });
    return dropList;
  }
  public _getData(): Promise<IOptionCategorie[]> {
    return sp.web.lists
      .getByTitle("Option")
      .items.select("Key", "Option")
      .get()
      .then((response: IOption[]) => {
        return response;
      });
  }
}
```

.tsx

```
export default class drop extends React.Component<IDropProps> {
  public dropOption: IDropdownOption[];
  constructor(props: IDropProps) {
    super(props);
    this.dropOption = props.dropList;
    this.state = {
      selectedItem: undefined
    };
  }
  public render(): JSX.Element {
    const { selectedItem } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <FocusZone direction={FocusZoneDirection.vertical}>
          <Dropdown
            className={classNames.dropDown}
            label=""
            selectedKey={selectedItem ? selectedItem.key : ""}
            onChange={this._onChange}
            options={this.dropOption}
          />
          //liste
        </FocusZone>
      </div>
    );
  }
  private _onChange = (
    event: React.FormEvent<HTMLDivElement>,
    item: IDropdownOption
  ): void => {
    const { optionList } = this.props;
    this.setState({
      selectedItem: item
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: What are you thinking when you have a react `render` method that doesn't return anything?

Comment: why did you say that my render doesn't return anything ? i don't undurstand

Comment: In your `.ts`  code, you have a `render` method that doesn't return what it renders.

Comment: I return dropList which i got from my getDropList() function

Comment: I'm talking about render. Why does it return void?

Comment: ah ok, i'm begginer in react and spfx, what must it return so that i can get my list?

Comment: I don't know if it will fix your problem, I was just noting that you had a component that returns nothing from its render method.  since that's a bug in and of itself, I figured I would call your attention to it.  I was just trying to be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you move the logic of binding drop down options to component(as async request of getting data and component life cycle).

Pass webpart context to component in render function like.

```
const element: React.ReactElement<IReactSpFxProps> = React.createElement(
            ReactSpFx,
          {
            description: this.properties.description,
            context:this.context,
            userToken: accessToken
          });

        ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
```

In component, declare variable to keep context.

```
import { WebPartContext } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
export interface IReactSpFxProps {
  description: string,
  context: WebPartContext,
  userToken:string
}
```

Implement   `public componentDidMount() {` to bind dropdonw options(replace with your data logic).

```
public componentDidMount() {
var reactHandler = this;
    this.props.context.spHttpClient.get(`${this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/items?select=ID,Title,Address,Pic`,
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1).then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        response.json().then((responseJSON: any) => {
          reactHandler.setState({
            items: responseJSON.value.sort()
          });
        });
      });
}
```

[one thread for your reference](http://www.sharepointsamples.com/spfx-load-sharepoint-list-items-in-a-dropdown-using-pnp-sp-js/)